# How to prevent a page from being linked in the menu/crossbar

Tags: links

I apologize if the question is confusing. Let me explain:

I'm running a modified version of Twentyten and I've been doing the parent/child thing with my pages, which show up on the horizontal menu that I like to call the crossbar. However, I want to add pages that are not linked to from there, only from a sidebar widget.

Unfortunately, I am not at all fluent when it comes to PHP...I've been trying to learn. Does anyone understand what I'm trying to do/have a solution?

EDIT: I ended up just making a seperate html document that uses the stylesheet and linked to it. Is there an outstanding reason NOT to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No php or extra page template necessary. See http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide and add/remove pages from the main menu and make a new sidebar menu. Or keep the page out of the main menu and add a simple href link to it in the sidebar.

Comment: Wow. I am crazy. Thank you so much! I really need to learn a lot more.